# Insufficient Privilege when editing a Task related to an object

Tags: administration, profile, user, tasks, owd

I have a TASK related to an object `abc__c`.

OWD for activity is- Controlled by Parent and the task is related to abc__c object that has `Read, Create, Edit on object level and Private on OWD.`

The user's profile has `"edit task" permission` as well. However the user is unable to edit the task owned by him where abc__c is also created by the same user.

User is unable to edit the TASK owned by them.Also the related To object is also owned by them.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the user has full access to the parent record, to edit the task I think you must have associated the user to that task or the user must be higher in role to that of assigned user or the user should have modify all permission in addition to edit task permission.

Please try the above and let me know if this helps.

Thanks,
Abhishek V

Comment: There is no role hierarchy. The user is associated or owns the task. The modify all permission should be on what object? The records are owned by user.